# ping to IP address works but ping to domain name not working

Tags: ping, nat

EDIT: I have 2 machine setup, Machine A only has internet connection, Machine B ens192 interface connects directly with Machine A interface ens192.

So configured iptables in MachineA to make sure Machine B also has the connectivity. ping to ip address works but domain name fails. Below provided each machine network config details.

**Machine A:**

Network config:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:11:8a:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 20.1.1.27/24 brd 20.1.1.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::88f2:48b:daef:7b0d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:1a:4b:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.67/24 brd 192.168.43.127 scope global noprefixroute ens224
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::65cb:5a44:210b:1ef3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have configured iptables NAT to allow packet comes from private network interface(ens192) to reach other interface(ens224) for intenet connectivity.
Below is the config used.

```
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ens224 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface ens192 -j ACCEPT
```

**Machine B:**

After configuring NAT rules in Machine A, Now able to ping 8.8.8.8 or any IP address from machine B, but unable to resolve any hostname.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.78 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.90 ms

[root@localhost ~]# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Network config:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:11:23:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 20.1.1.201/24 brd 20.1.1.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic ens192
       valid_lft 15108sec preferred_lft 15108sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe11:233a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 20.1.1.27 dev ens192 proto dhcp metric 100 
20.1.1.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 20.1.1.201 metric 100
```

resolv.conf

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 9.9.9.9
nameserver 20.1.1.27
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is `20.1.1.27` actually running a nameserver? (You've not mentioned this anywhere.) If it's not, there's no point including it in the `/etc/resolv.conf` configuration

Comment: @roaima 9.9.9.9 is  quad9 dns address.                                                            
 20.1.1.27 is the IP address of Machine A interface that receives incoming traffic from Machine B. I have removed it and kept only 9.9.9.9 and also tried 8.8.8.8 , still getting Name or service not known error

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware of Quad9 - thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

IP connection from **Machine B** seems to be working.

I would test if DNS servers under `resolf.conf` are valid.

```bsh
fping 9.9.9.9
fping 20.1.1.27
```

Check if DNS returs any data.

```bsh
nslookup google.com 9.9.9.9
nslookup google.com 20.1.1.27
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
host google.com 8.8.8.8
```

Check also **iptables**:

```bsh
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens224 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i ens224 -o ens192 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens224 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: fping and nslookup is not installed in my CentOS machine, so cant check it. Do I have to configure the iptables you have provided above in Machine B? Thanks..

Comment: So try ping instead of fping. If there is no nslookup, host should be there. iptabkes is just for configuration on machine you have a internet, machine A.

Comment: ping to 9.9.9.9 and 20.1.1.27 is working fine.  host google.com 8.8.8.8  - throws "connection timed out no servers could be reached".   I have provided the iptables configured on the MachineA in the original post. Is that correct?